# How to track GPS location of smart phone in react native

Tags: react-native, mobile, geolocation, gps, tracking

I am working on an app right now, which should track your GPS location to track your movements. Which mean your phone should track your position even when the app is not active.

How can I achieve this in react native? I've been struggling already a long time now.

Answer (score 0):

If you develop on Android you can use [Headless JS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android) with this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@shoaibmushtaq2/background-location-updates-in-react-native-using-work-manager-and-headless-js-91c0f0eab170).

If you are on IOS you can use this [library](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation).